# Axios Parse Error: Expected HTTP/ when request against Apple Push Sandbox API

Tags: node.js, axios

I'm trying to perform `POST https://api.sandbox.push.apple.com/messages/send/3/device/<TOKEN>` using `axios` library in a Node.JS environment. When performing the request, the following error is thrown:

`Error: Parse Error: Expected HTTP/`

When trying the same request using `http2` package, it work as expected, but I don't want to maintain two http request packages in my project, and I strongly prefer `axios`. Is this a missing configuration?

Comment: Getting the same. Not sure why. Works from postman, not from nodejs with node-fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have set the appropriate headers in the axios request. In the context of APNs(Apple Push Notification service), you need to set the apns-topic header. It should look something like this:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

const headers = {
  'apns-topic': 'your.bundle.id',
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${yourAuthenticationToken}`,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
};

const data = {
  // Your notification payload here
};

axios.post('https://api.sandbox.push.apple.com/3/device/<TOKEN>', data, { headers })
  .then(response => {
    // Handle the response
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Handle errors
  });
```

Comment: Please, pay attention to the issue reported. This is not related with the payload of the request. The issue is about the http client - axios - not being able to parse the Apple server response.

Answer (score -1):

Try the request using the HTTP protocol, like this:

```
http://api.sandbox.push.apple.com/messages/send/3/device/<TOKEN>
```

Comment: Apple doesn't accept HTTP connection, only HTTPS